# Placement new and delete in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++20

Let's imagine we have some class

```cpp
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(int& x) : x_(x) { x_++; }
    constexpr ~Foo() noexcept     { x_++; }

    int& x_;
};
```

In C++20 with `g++-10 -std=c++20` we can have a function like this:

```cpp
constexpr int do_foo_1() {
    int x = 0;
    Foo* p = new Foo(x);
    delete p;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(do_foo_1() == 2);
}
```

Let's try to divide operator `new` into memory allocation and inplace construction.
So new function looks like this:

```cpp
constexpr int do_foo_2() {
    int x = 0;
    Foo* p = static_cast<Foo*>(::operator new(sizeof(Foo)));
    p = ::new ((void*) p) Foo(x);
    p->~Foo();
    ::operator delete(p);
    return x;
}
```

But now there are two errors:
our memory allocation new and placement new are not constexpr!

```
error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘void* operator new(std::size_t)’
error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)’
```

So let's try to work around these errors. With `<memory>` we can have code like this:

```cpp
constexpr int do_foo_3() {
    std::allocator<Foo> alc;
    int x = 0;
    Foo* p = alc.allocate(1);
    p = std::construct_at(p, x);
    std::destroy_at(p);
    alc.deallocate(p, 1);
    return x;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(do_foo_3() == 2);
}
```

**Question**

What is the difference between my usage and usage of these operators in standard library?
Isn't the same thing happens in `std::construct_at` and `std::allocator<Foo>::allocate` under the hood?

**Note**

I tried to replicate std::construct_at by simply copying it implementation from `<stl_construct.h>` but I got same error:

```
error: ‘constexpr decltype (...) my_construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [...]’ called in a constant expression
error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the difference between my usage and usage of these operators in standard library?

Your usage is not called `std::allocator<T>::allocate` or `std::construct_at`.

These particular functions - along with a few others - are specifically [granted exceptions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#6) to the normal rule:

> For the purposes of determining whether an expression *E* is a core
> constant expression, the evaluation of a call to a member function of
> `std​::​allocator<T>` as defined in [allocator.members], where `T` is
> a literal type, does not disqualify *E* from being a core constant
> expression, even if the actual evaluation of such a call would
> otherwise fail the requirements for a core constant expression.
> Similarly, the evaluation of a call to `std​::​destroy_­at`,
> `std​::​ranges​::​destroy_­at`, `std​::​construct_­at`, or
> std​::​ranges​::​construct_­at does not disqualify *E* from being a
> core constant expression unless: [...]

As for plain `new` expressions, during constant evaluation [it never calls `::operator new`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.new#13):

> During an evaluation of a constant expression, a call to an allocation function is always omitted.

Comment: Does it mean, that i will never (in c++20) be able to make my own constexpr allocator?